# Can not connect to TOR network

Tags: windows

Tor was running well, but yesterday it stopped connecting. Here are the logs:

```
07.06.2016 17:29:27.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
07.06.2016 17:29:27.400 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
07.06.2016 17:29:27.800 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again. 
07.06.2016 17:29:34.200 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
07.06.2016 17:29:34.200 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
07.06.2016 17:29:34.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
07.06.2016 17:29:34.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
07.06.2016 17:29:36.100 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
07.06.2016 17:29:36.100 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'MaBishomarim' (fresh): $A832D176ECD5C7C6B58825AE22FC4C90FA249637~MaBishomarim at 154.35.22.11 
07.06.2016 17:29:36.100 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
07.06.2016 17:29:55.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:41213 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
07.06.2016 17:29:55.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 104.131.108.182:56880 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
07.06.2016 17:30:17.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.12:80 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
07.06.2016 17:31:27.200 [NOTICE] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:443. Giving up. (waiting for circuit) 
07.06.2016 17:33:40.100 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
07.06.2016 17:33:40.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
07.06.2016 17:33:40.100 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
07.06.2016 17:33:40.200 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```